# Hide all rows in a DataGridView using VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, search, filter, datagridview

I am trying to filter data in a DataGridView and I need to hide all rows and columns. I try to do this using looping list LINQ & lambda expressions because if I use a foreach it is slow when I try to filter 3000 rows.

The following code executes without errors and works perfectly in c# but doesn't hide the rows in vb:

c# works perfectly

```
dataGridView1.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => col.Visible = false);
```

vb doesnt works

```
datagrid.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList().ForEach(Function(obj) obj.Visible = False)
```

I'm looking for the equivalent code in vb.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the data and do your operations on the data itself - not the user interface. You can do similar to the following:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private allData As IEnumerable(Of Data) ' all your data
    Private filtered As IEnumerable(Of Data) ' filtered for logical and display purposes

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        allData = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(Function(i) New Data() With {.Value = i})
        updateFilteredNumbers(Function(d) True) ' filtered list initially identical to all
    End Sub
    Private Sub HideButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideButton.Click
        updateFilteredNumbers(Function(d) False)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ShowButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowButton.Click
        updateFilteredNumbers(Function(d) True)
    End Sub
    Private Sub EvenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EvenButton.Click
        updateFilteredNumbers(Function(d) d.Value Mod 2 = 0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub OddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OddButton.Click
        updateFilteredNumbers(Function(d) d.Value Mod 2 = 1)
    End Sub
    Private Async Sub updateFilteredNumbers(predicate As Func(Of Data, Boolean))
        ' perform filtering asynchronously, then update datasource on UI thread
        filtered = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() allData.Where(predicate).ToList())
        datagrid.DataSource = filtered
    End Sub

End Class

Public Structure Data ' Class to represent your data. Simple for this example
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Structure
```

This example can hide all, show all, or show odd or even values only. You can update the "filtered" collection and just refresh the DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

this will do exactly what you want

```
Dim dv As DataView
dv = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "name = 'Devcon' ", "type Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```